# ASP.NET ScriptControl & ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET MVC 3 (and more general with the ASP.NET MVC). I can not find any information whether it is possible to use my ScriptControl in ASP.NET MVC 3 project. The ScriptControl was implemented for my previous project in ASP.NET WebForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more common to use jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js intead of ScriptManager scripts to use ajax and it's more powerfull to use bundle (only for Mvc4) instead of ScriptManager to manage script links for different configurations and also to minify combine, control caching etc

Comment: So, I guess your answer is "No, it is impossible". Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: You cannot do it out of the box but there is already some implementation like this http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com. But the point point is for what are you going to use it?

Comment: This is more or less a general question. _Whether it is possible to use such controls in MVC3?_  If it is possible then _Which are advantages and disadvantages in that approach?_ Probably is is better to implement the control specially for the MVC

Comment: I have never faced off any solutions in asp.net mvc where ScriptManager was a must. For me generating some script links is not good by a controller couse you cannot control it, also even targeting script links you aren't aloud to minify convert or make some difficult in it. Advise some usefullcondition to use ScriptManager and we will diskuss it

Comment: К чёрту английский:) Мне совершенно не принципиально будет ли в проекте использоваться ScriptManager или нет, мне важно чтобы корректно работал legacy ScriptControl в MVC приложении. В WebForms для этого контрола важно наличае ScriptManager-а, как в MVC я не  знаю - поэтому и спрашиваю. Если это не типично для MVC, то я так понимаю, лучше реализовать этот контрол для MVC, а не пытаться засунуть его WebForms версию.

Comment: Если использовать контролы то лучше остаться на Webforms, большинство фич появившихся как фишки Mvc, доступны и для webForms, для razor контролы нельзя делать, для Mvc ASPX вроде можно (хотя не пробовал), но там синтаксис трехэтажный разметки. Вообще либо отказываться от контролов и нет надобности в ScriptManager либо WebForms

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. Instead of creating a new page in MVC 3 using Razor, use asp.net web pages for your view.

Although its not recommended. Do it, if you are too desperate.

Comment: it there any samples available? (step by step or so) :)